# Как сделать округлые края у <legend>?

Tags: html, css

Есть у меня `<legend>`
Мне нужно сделать его края не квадратными, а закруглёнными. Попробовал `border-radius` - не работает.
Есть идеи как это можно сделать?
Вот так нужно сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так же как и для любых других контейнеров можно использовать `border-radius:`

```css
legend {
  background: red;
  color:      white;
  
  padding:    10px;
  
  min-height: 50px;

  font-size:    20px;
  
  border-radius:  15px;
  
}
```

```html
<legend>какой-то текст легенды</legend>
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Таким образом вы делаете углы у самого текста. А мне нужно чтобы рамка самого тега была закруглённой.

Comment: Я лично у текста ничего не закругляю, я закругляю именно углы блока - `div`, `span`, `legend`  без разницы. Или вам что-то иное нужно?

Comment: Прикладываю скриншот, как это выглядит с вашим кодом

Comment: @NeoShima прикладывать нужно в тексте вопроса или в комментариях, а не через правку чужого сообщения.

Answer (score 2):

Вы скорее всего имели в виду тег `<fieldset >` :

```css
fieldset {
  min-height: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

legend {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Блок со скруглёнными краями</legend>
</fieldset>
```